# Double NIntegrate of a double exponential oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a double integral involving a double exponential oscillatory function:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iq^3} e^{-q^2}(q+b)\text{sign(q-b)}e^{ib^3} e^{-b^2}dq db
\end{equation}

i just used the following code

NIntegrate[$e^{-iq^3}$ $e^{-q^2}$ (q+b) $\text{sign(q-b)}$ $e^{ib^3}$ $e^{-b^2}$,{q,-$\infty$,$\infty$},{b,$-\infty$,$\infty$},Method -> {"DoubleExponentialOscillatory", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

and it gives the following message

```
Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the \
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly \
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

I tried using Method -> {"DoubleExponentialOscillatory", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0} in NIntegrate and it gives the following message

```
"Method \!\(\"DoubleExponentialOscillatory\"\) works only for \
one-dimensional integrals with infinite ranges. \
\!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\", Appearance->{Automatic, None}, \
BaseStyle->\"Link\", ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/NIntegrate\", \
ButtonNote->\"NIntegrate::oscir\"]\)"
```

How do I use NIntegrate? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the actual code you used.

Comment: sorry about that. i just added it

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: sorry about that but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 3):

For every point `{q, b}` in the integrand, there is another point with the values of `q` and `b` interchanged, and the value of the integrand is the negative of the first point.  So, the integral must be zero, and that is why Mathematica gives the first error message in the question.

This can be seen explicitly as follows.  Define variables `x` and `y` as follows.

```
Solve[{q - b == x, q + b == y}, {q, b}] // First

(* {q -> (x + y)/2, b -> 1/2 (-x + y)} *)
```

Then, the integrand becomes

```
Simplify[Exp[-q^2 - I q^3 - b^2 - I b^3] (q + b) Sign[q - b] /. %]

(* E^(-(1/4) I (y^2 (-2 I + y) + x^2 (-2 I + 3 y))) y Sign[x] *)
```

and

```
Integrate[%, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* 0 *)
```

as expected.

Comment: sorry about that. i had a typo.

Comment: Answer still is zero, for the same reason.

Comment: Another way to show your point: `int[q_, b_] := Exp[-q^2 - I q^3 - b^2 - I b^3] (q + b) Sign[q - b]; int[q, b] + int[b, q] // Simplify`, since the integrals of $f(x,y)$ and $f(y,x)$ over the plane are the same for any integrable function. (+1)